# How to transmit different parameters

Tags: flutter, dart, random, parameters

I have a widget in which I create random color

```
  Set<Color> getColorSet({int numberOfColor = 3}) {
  Set<Color> generatedColorSet = Set<Color>();
  while (generatedColorSet.length != numberOfColor) {
    generatedColorSet.add(
      Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
    );
  }
  return generatedColorSet;
}

  Set<Color> colorSet = Set<Color>();

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    colorSet = getColorSet();
  }
```

and random dimensions/coordinates for a button

```
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    double maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

Random randomT = new Random();

    int minT = 3;
    int maxT = maxHeight.toInt() - 80;
    int randomTop = minT + randomT.nextInt(maxT - minT);

Random randomL = new Random();

    int minL = 3;
    int maxL = maxWidth.toInt() - 80;
    int randomLeft = minL + randomL.nextInt(maxL - minL);

Random randomH = new Random();

    int minH = 70;
    int maxH = maxHeight.toInt() - randomTop;
    int randomHeight = minH + randomH.nextInt(maxH - minH);

Random randomW = new Random();

    int minW = 70;
    int maxW = maxWidth.toInt() - randomLeft;
    int randomWidth = minW + randomW.nextInt(maxW - minW);

Random randomR = new Random();

    int minR = 1;
    int maxR = 75;
    int randomRadius = minR + randomR.nextInt(maxR - minR);
```

I pass these values to the button located inside the Stack

```
   Container(
        child: Positioned(
          height: randomHeight.toDouble(), 
          width: randomWidth.toDouble(),
          top: randomTop.toDouble(), 
          left: randomLeft.toDouble(), 
          child: SizedBox(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(colorSet.elementAt(0)),
                overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(colorSet.elementAt(1)),
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(randomRadius.toDouble()),
                    side: BorderSide(color: colorSet.elementAt(2), width: 5),
                  ), 
                ),
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(70,70)), 
              ),
                  onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  colorSet = getColorSet();
                });
              },
              child: const Text(
                'PRESS',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), 
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

The problem is that if I want to add another button inside the Stack, it will get the same values as the other one and will overlap it and have the same colors. How do I pass my random values different for each button ?

Below is my widget entirely with two buttons that now have the same values

```
class ButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
   const ButtonWidget({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ButtonWidget> createState() => _ButtonWidgetState();
}

class _ButtonWidgetState extends State<ButtonWidget> {
  
  Set<Color> getColorSet({int numberOfColor = 3}) {
  Set<Color> generatedColorSet = Set<Color>();
  while (generatedColorSet.length != numberOfColor) {
    generatedColorSet.add(
      Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
    );
  }
  return generatedColorSet;
}

  Set<Color> colorSet = Set<Color>();

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    colorSet = getColorSet();
  }

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

double maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    Random randomT = new Random();

        int minT = 3;
        int maxT = maxHeight.toInt() - 80;
        int randomTop = minT + randomT.nextInt(maxT - minT);

    Random randomL = new Random();

        int minL = 3;
        int maxL = maxWidth.toInt() - 80;
        int randomLeft = minL + randomL.nextInt(maxL - minL);

    Random randomH = new Random();
    
        int minH = 70;
        int maxH = maxHeight.toInt() - randomTop;
        int randomHeight = minH + randomH.nextInt(maxH - minH);

    Random randomW = new Random();

        int minW = 70;
        int maxW = maxWidth.toInt() - randomLeft;
        int randomWidth = minW + randomW.nextInt(maxW - minW);

    Random randomR = new Random();

        int minR = 1;
        int maxR = 75;
        int randomRadius = minR + randomR.nextInt(maxR - minR);

    return Stack(
      children: [ 
        Container(
        child: Positioned(
          height: randomHeight.toDouble(), 
          width: randomWidth.toDouble(),
          top: randomTop.toDouble(), 
          left: randomLeft.toDouble(), 
          child: SizedBox(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(colorSet.elementAt(0)),
                overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(colorSet.elementAt(1)),
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(randomRadius.toDouble()),
                    side: BorderSide(color: colorSet.elementAt(2), width: 5),
                  ), 
                ),
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(70,70)), 
              ),
                  onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  colorSet = getColorSet();
                });
              },
              child: const Text(
                'PRESS',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), 
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Positioned(
          height: randomHeight.toDouble(), 
          width: randomWidth.toDouble(),
          top: randomTop.toDouble(), 
          left: randomLeft.toDouble(), 
          child: SizedBox(   
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(colorSet.elementAt(0)),
                overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(colorSet.elementAt(1)),
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(randomRadius.toDouble()),
                    side: BorderSide(color: colorSet.elementAt(2), width: 5),
                  ), 
                ),
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(70,70)),
              ),
                  onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  colorSet = getColorSet();
                });
              },
              child: const Text(
                'PRESS',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), 
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),   
      ), 
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a general advice. You don't need to create a new `Random()` instance every time you need some random numbers. You can just create a single global instance and reuse it around your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generated data one time and pass it to two widgets. You should generate data for each button.

Move your button to separate class and generate data there. Then use this class two or several times in your stack.

```
class MyRandomizedButton extends StatefulWidget {

  const MyRandomizedButton({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static Set<Color> _getColorSet({int numberOfColor = 3}) {
    final generatedColorSet = <Color>{};
    while (generatedColorSet.length != numberOfColor) {
      generatedColorSet.add(
        Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
      );
    }
    return generatedColorSet;
  }

  @override
  State<MyRandomizedButton> createState() => _MyRandomizedButtonState();
}

class _MyRandomizedButtonState extends State<MyRandomizedButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    final random = Random();

    int minT = 3;
    int maxT = maxHeight.toInt() - 80;
    int randomTop = minT + random.nextInt(maxT - minT);

    int minL = 3;
    int maxL = maxWidth.toInt() - 80;
    int randomLeft = minL + random.nextInt(maxL - minL);

    int minH = 70;
    int maxH = maxHeight.toInt() - randomTop;
    int randomHeight = minH + random.nextInt(maxH - minH);

    int minW = 70;
    int maxW = maxWidth.toInt() - randomLeft;
    int randomWidth = minW + random.nextInt(maxW - minW);

    int minR = 1;
    int maxR = 75;
    int randomRadius = minR + random.nextInt(maxR - minR);

    final colorSet = MyRandomizedButton._getColorSet();

    return Positioned(
      height: randomHeight.toDouble(),
      width: randomWidth.toDouble(),
      top: randomTop.toDouble(),
      left: randomLeft.toDouble(),
      child: SizedBox(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(colorSet.elementAt(0)),
            overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(colorSet.elementAt(1)),
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(randomRadius.toDouble()),
                side: BorderSide(color: colorSet.elementAt(2), width: 5),
              ),
            ),
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.all(10)),
            minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(const Size(70, 70)),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: const Text(
            'PRESS',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Use:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    MyRandomizedButton(key: ValueKey("1")),
    MyRandomizedButton(key: ValueKey("2")),
  ]
)
```